Problems with looping iterations in my Java program
I have a code with a little problem because My iterations do not turn out well
I need that when I enter 6 specific numbers (7,5,3,4,8,2) it gives me 4 exact iterations that create
(7,5,3,4,8,2)
(12,8,7,12,10,2)
(19,20,17,14,10,2)
(29,22,17,14,10,2)

But the code only gets the first number of the iterations right and the rest don't.
here is the code:
package sumas;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumaPrefijo {
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static void printArray(int[] array) {
        System.out.print(" [");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%2d | ", array[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        

        int n; // array Length
        int[] array; // numbers to add
        int steps; // number of parallel additions
        int PUs; // number of processing unitis

        System.out.print("Cuantos numeros deseas sumar? ");
        n = input.nextInt();
        array = new int[n];

        System.out.print("Introduce los valores a sumar");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.printf(" Num %d? = ", (i + 1));
            array[i] = input.nextInt();

        }

        System.out.println("Arreglo inicial");
        printArray(array);

        
        steps = (int) Math.ceil(Math.log(n) / Math.log(2));
        System.out.println(" Pasos = " + steps);
        PUs = n / 2;
        System.out.println("procesadores = " + PUs);

        for (int j = 0; j < steps; j++) {
            System.out.println("Pasos" + (j + 1));
            
            for (int i = 0; i < PUs; i++) { // for all existe
                if (2 * i + (int) Math.pow(2, j) < n) {
                    array[2 * i] = array[2 * i] + array[2 * i + (int) Math.pow(2, j)];

                }
            }
            printArray(array);
        }
        System.out.println(" El resultado de la suma es = " + array[0]);
    }
}


Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.
Please see: What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?. What is the logic behind the expected loop iterations? What are (7,5,3,4,8,2), (12,8,7,12,10,2), (19,20,17,14,10,2) and (29,22,17,14,10,2) supposed to be?

@Isaias can you provide the above code snippet all in English language..

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To help folks understand the problem, please edit your question and explain what you are trying to do.  Just posting some expected output does not explain what you are trying to do with the numbers to reach that output.

You've got some understanding about the powers of 2, but you don't need any logic about "steps" or "processing units". The indicies are all incremental, so no multiplication needed
This will start at index 1, then 2, then 4 while adding to the left side of the array
int[] arr = new int[] {7,5,3,4,8,2};

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

for (int pow = 0; pow < arr.length/2; pow++) {
    int offset = (int) Math.pow(2, pow);  // where to start from 
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - offset; i++) {
        arr[i] += arr[i+offset];
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}

Result
[7, 5, 3, 4, 8, 2]
[12, 8, 7, 12, 10, 2]
[19, 20, 17, 14, 10, 2]
[29, 22, 17, 14, 10, 2]

